# Ripple Effect Buttons CSS3

Tags: css, button

Here is a code from W3Schools on how to create a ripple effect button.

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:after {
    content: "";
    background: #f1f1f1;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 300%;
    padding-left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px !important;
    margin-top: -120%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 15s;
}

.button:active:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0s;
}
```

Can someone help me understand the code bit by bit, especially why the padding and margin in the button:after are so highly set and how the zero values in the button:active:after affect the animation?

Any help will be highly appreciated. (I know the basic of padding and margin, but I think that I am not getting the 'after' class and the technique used).

Comment: so, was my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

`:after` is not a class is a pseudo-element that it's used to add content to the content of an element .see here **[::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after)**

so it uses that `pseudo-element` to create a new `space` with CSS that it's not defined in your initial HTML . it's like making another element inside the button

for eg if you had a structure like this :

```css
.no_pseudo, .with_pseudo { 
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  margin:40px 0
}

.likeAfter {
  background:blue;
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
height:100%;}


.with_pseudo { 
  position:relative;
}

.with_pseudo:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background:blue;
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
height:100%;
lefT:0;
right:0;}
```

```html
<div class="no_pseudo">
  <div class="likeAfter">
  </div>
</div>


<div class="with_pseudo">
 
</div>
```

as you can see, the `:after` element can be used just like a child element inside a div. but you can achieve that just by using CSS .you don't have to change the HTML structure.

so this trick is using `:after` , which has a `background: #f1f1f1;` and it's positioned under the button  ( `margin-top:-120%` ) . and then, when you click on the button , it has (`margin:0` ) that's how this effect is done

also with paddings and opacity.

i would've done it differently :

```css
.button {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
     z-index:2;
}

.button:after {
    content: "pseudo element >!<";
    color:green;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    height:0%;
    width:0%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 3s;
   
}

.button:focus:after {
   width:50%;
   height:100%;
    opacity: 1;
    

}
```

```html
<button class="button">
I AM A BUTTON
</button>
```

i positioned the `:after` at the bottom-left of the `button` , with `width:0%;height:0%;opacity:0` ;

then, when i click on the button, i added `width:50%;height:100%;opacity:1` on the `:after` and that's how you get that effect . maybe is not exactly the same as in your example but it works.

also added some `content:""` to the `:after` element. you can add text,images etc. almost anything. but if you don't want to add anything, you must use `content:""` and leave it empty, otherwise the `:after` is not created.

`:before` is the same as after > see here more about pseudo elements

[css_pseudo_elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) or here [Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

there is much to talk about this things, but i hope you kind of understood what's going on with the `pseudo-elements` and with this effect. let me know. cheers !

EDIT AFTER COMMENT :

**1.** ' transition backwards ' is because of the `:active` state ( **[:active](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp)** ) . the button has the `:active` state only when you click on it . after that  it's not active anymore and `:after` goes back to it's original style

and because it has `transition:15s` it takes 15 sec to get back to it's original position and color.

the same with the ripple effect. you click on the button, the effects starts , `:after` gets from one style to another , for example from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1`  then because the button doesn't have `:active` state anymore, `:after` returns to it's original style of `opacity:0` , all this happens in 15 seconds ( because of the `transition:15s` )

**2**
`content:""` inserts the space for the `:after` or `:before` into the HTML structure

you need `content:""` on `:after` because , as i said in the beginning ,

> ::after is a pseudo element which allows you to insert content onto a page from CSS (without it needing to be in the HTML). While the end result is not actually in the DOM, it appears on the page as if it is

key word `content` . so even if you don't insert text or images but you just want to insert an empty space , you need to set up a `content:""` which means empty but still there .

`elem:after{content:""}` generates a space with `width:0;height:0` after the element.

i will make two short examples , one with something inside `content:""` one with nothing inside it

```css
h1:before {
  content:"i am before < < < ";
  font-size:14px;
  color:red;
  }
  h1:after {
  content:" > > > i am after";
  font-size:14px;
  color:blue;
  }

h2:before {
  content:"";
  background:red;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  position:absolute;
  }
h2:after {
  content:"";
  background:blue;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  position:absolute;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Text Before me </h1>


<h2>Just empty content </h2>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the concept of _:after_. However, one question, in the last state, [button:active:after], I see that transition: 0s. This seems to make the transition backwards. Why? Also, why _content:""_? Why _:after_ is not created otherwise?